# Python + comet + web (chat) - I need working(!) library/server

Tags: python, comet

I need working (cross-browser) project (library/server) to build web-chat in comet technology. There are: orbited, orbited2, hookbox, but it seems that are no longer developed (also projects sites are down) and have a lot of bugs.

Any ideas?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Orbited still works nicely, it's pretty stable, actually. You might have to fumble around a bit to find the right version of twisted-web for it to work properly, but other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Not exactly. I run latest version from trunk and it doesn't work under Opera and has memory lake ;/

Comment: Hmm... I wish I could remember the version that worked fine for me (it wasn't the latest), but alas, I no longer work in the place where I had to use it.

Comment: I deployed my comet server using Orbited 0.7.10. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) a simple non-blocking webserver written in Python by the facebook team.

The comet behavior can be done with [tornadio](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio) which makes possible to use socket.io javascript lib with tornado.

There is a chat example in tornadio that may look like what you are looking for. I 've tested it successfully with IE6, Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

I hope it helps

Comment: Looks really nice! Thanks. I'll try to merged this project with redis for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Shaveet](https://github.com/urielka/shaveet) is a zero-config JSONP/CORS long-polling(AKA comet) server, that has chat apps as examples.